# Cómo puedo poner el resultado de un php foreach en un carrusel de bootstrap

Tags: php, foreach, carrusel

Tengo una tabla de noticias en mi BD y quiero listar la imagen en un carrusel. Tengo un modelo vista controlador y una función listar en el controlador a la que llamo en el fichero index.php para que liste las noticias. Sé que tengo que hacer un foreach y con el getImagen(), para que me muestre todas las imágenes almacenadas en la BD, lo que no sé es como ponerlo, ya que en el ejemplo se pone directamente las slides que tiene el carrusel.

Este es mi fichero index.php

```html
<?php

require_once(__DIR__.'/../lib/controller/UsuarioController.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../lib/controller/NoticiaController.php');

session_start();

$cnt = new NoticiaController();
$list = $cnt->listarN();

?>

<html>
<body>

 <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
    <div id="carousel-example-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <!--Indicators-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!--/.Indicators-->
        <!--Slides-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="view">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
                    <p>First text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <!--Mask color-->
                <div class="view">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="/WebBurger/public/img/noticias/burger.png" width="1366" height="603" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" alt="Second slide">
                    <div class="mask rgba-black-strong"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
                    <p>Secondary text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <!--Mask color-->
                <div class="view">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg" alt="Third slide">
                    <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
                    <p>Third text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Slides-->
        <!--Controls-->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
        <!--/.Controls-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->

    <!-- Carousel noticias -->

</body>


</html>
```

este es mi fichero NoticiaController.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../model/DB/NoticiaDB.php');

class NoticiaController{
    
    public function listarN(){
        $adaptadordb = new NoticiaDB();
        $lista = $adaptadordb->listarNoticias();
        
        return $lista;
    }
    
}
```

Este es mi fichero NoticiaDB.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../Noticia.php');

class NoticiaDB{
    
    private $conexion;
    
    public function listarNoticias(){
        $this->conectar();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias";
        $stm = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
        
        $stm->execute();
        $result = $stm->get_result();
        
        $ret = array();
        while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $curr = new Noticia($r['id_noticia'], $r['titulo'], $r['descripcion'],
                $r['fecha'], $r['imagen']);
            array_push($ret, $curr);
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    
      private function conectar(){
        if($this->conexion == null){
            $this->conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "BD");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Este es mi fichero Noticia.php donde hago los Get y Set de los atributos de la tabla noticias

```html
<?php 

class Noticia{
    
    private $_id_noticia;
    private $_titulo;
    private $_descripcion;
    private $_fecha;
    private $_imagen;
    
    public function __construct($id = null, $t = null, $d = null, $f = null, $i = null){
        $this->setId_noticia($id);
        $this->setTitulo($t);
        $this->setDescripcion($d);
        $this->setFecha($f);
        $this->setImagen($i);
        
    }
    
    
    public function getId_noticia()
    {
        return $this->_id_noticia;
    }
    
    public function getTitulo()
    {
        return $this->_titulo;
    }
    
    public function getDescripcion()
    {
        return $this->_descripcion;
    }

    public function getFecha()
    {
        return $this->_fecha;
    }
    
    public function getImagen()
    {
        return $this->_imagen;
    }
    

    public function setId_noticia($_id_noticia)
    {
        $this->_id_noticia = $_id_noticia;
    }
    
    public function setTitulo($_titulo)
    {
        $this->_titulo = $_titulo;
    }
    
    public function setDescripcion($_descripcion)
    {
        $this->_descripcion = $_descripcion;
    }

    public function setFecha($_fecha)
    {
        $this->_fecha = $_fecha;
    }

    
    public function setImagen($_imagen)
    {
        $this->_imagen = $_imagen;
    }
    
    public function toArray(){
        $obj = [];
        $obj['id_noticia'] = $this->getId_noticia();
        $obj['titulo'] = $this->getTitulo();
        $obj['descripcion'] = $this->getDescripcion();
        $obj['fecha'] = $this->getFecha();
        $obj['imagen'] = $this->getImagen();
        
        return $obj;
    }
    
    
}
```

Si me podéis echar una mano y decirme en que parte del carrusel tendría que hacer el foreach por favor. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debes iterar 
1) los controles
2) las imágenes

Es decir tienes que iterar los <LI> como tantos vinculos a imagenes tengas, de las misma forma el contenedor de la imagen <div class="carousel-item"> considerando los active  para indice 0 o primer indice.

Comment: Que tipo de estructura de datos obtienes en :"$list" (o sea me refiero a que si es un objeto, conjunto de objetos,un array o un conjuntos de array),dependiendo de eso sera mas facil poder realizar lo que deseas. Seria bueno que muestres los datos que recibes en la variable $list.

Comment: @Santiago te he puesto en la pregunta los ficheros que tengo del modelo vista controlador que he implementado. El $list coge la funciín listarN del controlador, que si haces todo el recorrido hacia abajo con el NoticiaDB.php y el Noticia.php coge todos los atributos de la BD para poder listarlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De esta forma puedes imprimir los enlaces que tiene en la **BD** en tu **carousel**, solo debes de realizar un `forEach` dentro de tu etiqueta: `<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">`,aquí el código:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    
         <?php  $contador=0;
                if(!empty($list) AND count($list) > 0){
                        foreach ($list as $key => $fila) {?>


                            <?php   if($contador==0){ ?>
                                       <div class="carousel-item active">
                                            <div class="view">
                                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo $fila->getImagen(); ?>" alt="First slide">
                                                <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                <h3 class="h3-responsive"><?php echo $fila->getTitulo();?> </h3>
                                                <p>First text</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                            <?php $contador=1;
                                    }else{ ?>
                                        <div class="carousel-item">
                                            <div class="view">
                                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo $fila->getImagen(); ?>" alt="First slide">
                                                <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                                <h3 class="h3-responsive"><?php echo $fila->getTitulo();?> </h3>
                                                <p>First text</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                            <?php   } ?>
                           
                            
        <?php           }       
                }  
        ?>    
            
            
        </div>
```

El **contador** que utilice:`$contador=0;`  es para distinguir el `"carousel-item active"`  de los  `"carousel-item"`  ya que la primera imagen que se muestra es la que toma el foco.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente! Muy amable!

Comment: Para evitar repetir todo el código y controlar si es la primera imagen para ponerla como activa, puedes hacerlo más sencillo y te ahorras unas cuantas líneas. Puedes usar:

    class="carousel-item <?php echo $contador == 0? "active": "" ?>"